# Setting include_blank for an f.select with options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my View:

```
<%= f.select :blood_group, options_for_select([
              ['O+', Membership.blood_groups.keys[0]], ['O-', Membership.blood_groups.keys[1]],
              ], @user.blood_group) %>
```

How do I add `include_blank` attribute to the above? When I just append it at the end, I get the error "wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)"

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
<%= f.select :blood_group, [['', nil], ['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3], ['four', 4], ['five', 5], ['', nil]]
```

its optional to specify `options_for_select` note that this add two blanks field at the beginning and in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this following as:

```
<%= f.select :blood_group, options_for_select([
    ['O+', Membership.blood_groups.keys[0]], 
    ['O-', Membership.blood_groups.keys[1]]], @user.blood_group, {include_blank: true}, {}) %>
```

You can refer document at: [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

Comment: I tried that. Gives the error "wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)"